# Update com Select

Tags: mysql, sql

Sou novo no fórum e em SQL.
Eu utilizo o SGBD MySQL Workbench para tentar aprender a sintaxe.
Consultando um site de tutorial, fui realizar um update utilizando um select, segue linha de comando:

```
update actor
set salario = salario * 1.1
where salario = (select min(salario) from actor)
```

Mas ele me retorna um erro e eu não faço a mínima ideia de como conseguir resolver:

> "Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'actor' for update
>   in FROM clause"

Fiz o select separado para ver se eu estava errando na sintaxe, mas rodou tranquilamente.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema acontece pois o MySQL não permite que você atualize uma tabela e use a mesma para definir o critério de `update`.

Acho que isso pode resolver seu problema:

```
update actor
set salario = salario * 1.1
where salario in
(
  select salario from
  (
    select min(salario)
    from actor
  ) as minSalario
)
```

Assim, você cria uma tabela temporária pra poder conseguir usá-la no update.

Comment: E quanto ao erro? Seria interessante explicar o motivo que dispara tal erro.

Comment: Tinha um rapaz que já tinha comentado, mas apagou, vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Fui eu, mas não tinha embasamento, não achei ainda na documentação essa informação.

Comment: Tava certo o que você tinha dito, mesmo assim vou atualizar para que outras pessoas saibam também.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Vocês recomendam algum site bacana para eu aprender?