# Query delete com Join mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Pessoal tenho problema com esse query não sei o que esta errado:

```
DELETE FROM mdl_forum_discussions WHERE id IN 
(
SELECT mdl_forum_discussions.id 
    FROM mdl_forum_discussions 
    LEFT JOIN mdl_forum_posts ON mdl_forum_discussions.id = mdl_forum_posts.discussion 
    WHERE mdl_forum_discussions.id = 4
);
```

Retorna este erro:

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'mdl_forum_discussions' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Que problema? nao deleta o que precisava? da uma exceção ? posta qual é o problema tambem assim fica meio  generico.

Comment: Adicione mais informações, qual erro está retornando, a subquerie sozinha está funcionando?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Update com Select](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109363/update-com-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você não pode em um `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, ou `INSERT` referenciar a mesma tabela em um subquery, porém existe uma solução:

```
DELETE FROM mdl_forum_discussions WHERE id IN 
(
SELECT mdl_forum_discussions.id 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM mdl_forum_discussions) as mfd 
    LEFT JOIN mdl_forum_posts ON mfd.id = mdl_forum_posts.discussion 
    WHERE mfd.id = 4
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Conforme o @Kenny já respondeu, não é possível dar o comando `DELETE` ao mesmo tempo que se faz um `SELECT`. Uma outra solução que você pode adotar é:

```
DELETE A FROM mdl_forum_discussions AS A
LEFT JOIN mdl_forum_posts AS B
  ON (A.id = B.discussion)
WHERE B.id = 4;
```

Se atente para colocar o alias da tabela logo após o comando `DELETE`, caso contrário, os registros de ambas as tabelas serão deletados.