# Erro SQL (1093): You can't specify target table 'import2016' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Estou executando esse PROCEDURE, e ela retorna esse erro!

```
BEGIN
        SET @cont = 0;
        REPEAT
            SET @sqlstring = "UPDATE import2016 SET coluna4 = (SELECT coluna4 FROM import2016 AS a WHERE a.coluna2 ='' and a.coluna4 like'%/%' LIMIT ?,01) WHERE id = (SELECT id+7 FROM import2016 AS a WHERE a.coluna2 ='' and a.coluna4 like'%/%' LIMIT ?,01);";
            PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstring ;
            EXECUTE stmt USING @cont,@cont;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
            SET @cont = @cont +1;
        UNTIL @cont = 256
        END REPEAT;
    END


/* Erro SQL (1093): You can't specify target table 'import2016' for update in FROM clause */
```

A PROCEDURE está no mesmo banco da tabela!
Gostaria de saber como posso resolver este erro, obrigado.

Comment: já tentou utilizar os alias que você colocou nas subqueries ? `UPDATE import2016 SET coluna4 = (SELECT a.coluna4 FROM import2016 AS a WHERE a.coluna2 ='' and a.coluna4 like'%/%' LIMIT ?,01) WHERE id = (SELECT a.id+7 FROM import2016 AS a WHERE a.coluna2 ='' and a.coluna4 like'%/%' LIMIT ?,01);`

Comment: Desculpe mas não intendi oque você quis dizer, desde já agradeço pela resposta!

Comment: na subquerie, você colocou o alias da tabela `import2016` como `a` [`import2016 AS a`], mas a coluna do select foi apenas `coluna4`, sem o alias. Apenas sugeri que colocasse o alias também nos sub selects, pois o SGDB pode entender que aquela coluna se trata da tabela que está informada no update. (Mesmo sendo a mesma tabela)

Comment: Desta Forma? `"UPDATE import2016 AS a SET a.coluna4 = (SELECT a.coluna4 FROM import2016 AS a WHERE a.coluna2 ='' and a.coluna4 like'%/%' LIMIT ?,01) WHERE id = (SELECT a.id+7 FROM import2016 AS a WHERE a.coluna2 ='' and a.coluna4 like'%/%' LIMIT ?,01);";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando o conceito que o @Rovann Linhalis disse:

> na subquerie, você colocou o alias da tabela import2016 como a
>   [import2016 AS a], mas a coluna do select foi apenas coluna4, sem o
>   alias. Apenas sugeri que colocasse o alias também nos sub selects,
>   pois o SGDB pode entender que aquela coluna se trata da tabela que
>   está informada no update. (Mesmo sendo a mesma tabela)

e a resposta de outra pergunta aqui no stackoverflow:

[Update com Select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109363/update-com-select?rq=1)

Assim que a query ficou :

```
UPDATE capaobonito_import.import2016_copy 
SET coluna4 = 
(   
    SELECT b.coluna4 FROM import2016 AS b 
    WHERE b.coluna2 ='' and b.coluna4 like'%/%' LIMIT 00,01
) 
WHERE id =
(
    SELECT a.id+7 FROM import2016_copy_copy AS a 
    WHERE a.coluna2 ='' and a.coluna4 like'%/%' LIMIT 00,01
);
```

Grato pela ajuda da Comunidade, em especifico os autores de comentário e respostas referenciados aqui.